# What's that little button with the squares called?

Tags: buttons

On my Motorola, it has four squares and the top-left square is solid. I'm not sure if all Android phones have it. "Home", "back", and "search" all seem pretty straightforward. Does it have a specific name or is it just "menu"?

(can you tell I'm new to Android?)

Comment: FWIW mine is a bunch of lines.

Comment: I think the line design on the og droid makes sense. It looks like a dropdown menu. have no idea why motorola would think a bunch of squares is a good representation for a menu.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it's called the **Menu Key**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found some great info on the phone's buttons from AT&T's site too: [Motorola Flipside Tutorial](http://att.deviceanywhere.com/MotorolaFlipside/tutorials/8285)

[image: Motorola Flipside - closed]

> **Closed View**
>
> 1. Earpiece: Lets you hear the caller and automated prompts.
> 2. Power/Sleep: End a call / Turn off the device / Sleep mode.
> 3. Micro USB: Charge the phone or connect to a PC.
> 4. Menu: Press to access sub-menus with additional options for different
>      features and applications.
> 5. Home: Press to return to the Home screen.
> 6. Microphone: Captures audio.
> 7. Trackpad: Use to select small items in the display, or control a game
>      without blocking your view. Just flick
>      across the pad to scroll or move, and
>      press the pad to select.
> 8. Back: Press to return to the previous screen.
> 9. Search: Press for text search; press and hold for voice search.
> 10. Camera: Use to take pictures and shoot videos.
> 11. Volume: Use to adjust the volume.
> 12. 3.5mm Headset: Allows you to plug in a headset with a 3.5mm connector.

[image: Motorola Flipside - open]

> **Open View**
>
> - 13..Shift: Capitalizes letters during text entry.
> - 14..Alternate: Inserts alternate characters.
> - 15.. Menu: Press to access sub-menus with additional options for different
>     features and applications.
> - 16..Back: Press to return to previous screen.
> - 17..Search: Press for text search; press and hold for voice search.
> - 18..Space: Enters a space into text.
> - 19..Symbols: Opens a table of symbols.
> - 20..Scroll/Select: Use to navigate up/down and right/left on the screen.
> - 21..New Line: Start a new line; sends message when text messaging. Also
>     known as the Enter key.
> - 22..Delete: Press to delete text.